# Linking to external file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Linking to external file in Ruby on Rails

I have a file I want to share as a link in my rails app.
I create a link to it in the .erb file like this

```
<li><a href="somefile.pdf">Some File</a> </li>
```

When I select the link I get the following error.

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/pages/somefile.pdf"
>   with {:method=>:get}

Do I really need a route for this? I really just want the save as dialog to popup. Just a link to a file that the user can open or download.

What is the rails way to do this (rails newbie here)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place the file in the app's `public/` directory and use a forward slash at the start of the path in your link's href.

The problem you are having is because `href="somefile.pdf"` is relative to the current URL which is probably something like `http://localhost:3000/pages/42`. By using `href="/somefile.pdf"` instead the resolved URL will be `http://localhost:3000/somefile.pdf` (rather than `http://localhost:3000/pages/somefile.pdf`) and it won't conflict with your pages routes.

Answer (score -1):

You could also just do <%= Link_to "name of link", "http://pathoffilehere.pdf" %>

Don't forget the quotes....  :)

Comment: According the question, the file is inside the OP's app. If you change the domain (from working in dev mode in localhost to prod mode in http://yourdomain.com) this is going to break.