# How to link to local file with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, hyperlink, local

I'm new to Ruby. I worked through [Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-development_tools) and now I'm creating my own site, locally on my mac localhost:3000 , based on what I've learned. I want to link to a .docx file on a page. The file is located locally on my laptop, in the public directory of my ruby project. I want whoever clicks the link to be prompted to download the file. How do I do this? Or is this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891867/linking-to-external-file-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1

Comment: Thank link did it. Thanks